# Running a series of functions in parallel to answer an HTTP request

Tags: python, http, parallel-processing, gevent

I have experimented with various approaches to this and would like to see what you guys thought was the best approach to solving this problem in Python.

Basically, I have a web service that accepts requests provided a single query term and proceeds to perform a series of computations, in parallel, with that term. These computations can be thought of as individual function calls.

The idea being that as soon as the request comes in, I call the functions asynchronously, and hold the request until results start to trickle in.

From my research, it seems like using a library like [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) is probably the best way to go, although I am still not entirely familiar with greenlets. Also, it seems like in order to accomplish the type of functionality I am looking for (for results to be sent back to the client via the long request as they become available), I need to use a special type of StreamServer that supports this. The response itself is just JSON objects to be read in by a JavaScript module in the frontend, which in turn will update a UI component as these are sent back to the browser.

What is the best approach to doing this? Does it make sense to use something like gevent or should this instead be implemented using co-routines without the assistance of a library? I am sure that this is something that has been done a lot in the past by many people around here and I wanted to gather some recommendations.

Thanks a ton in advance, let me know if you'd like more details, and I look forward to hearing  about your suggestions!

Comment: The question would be, what is the best approach to doing this? Does it make sense to use something like gevent or should this instead be implemented using coroutines without the assistance of a library? I am sure that this is something that has been done a lot in the past by many people around here and I wanted to gather some recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "computations" you speak of are not CPU-bound, `gevent` would be awesome for that kind of thing. Your request handler could look like this:

```
def handle_request(request):
    ...
    pool = gevent.pool.Group()
    results = group.map(do_computation, input_data)
    return results
```

If they are CPU-bound, though, you'll need to consider [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html), as Python is in general pretty poor when it comes to CPU-bound tasks in single operating system process.